# Как тестировать адаптивный сайт?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, веб-дизайн

Лучшее тестирование адаптивного сайта — это само устройство, но такого количества устройств явно у фрилансера не найдется. Как же качественно протестировать адаптивный сайт, чтобы с уверенностью можно было отдать работу заказчику?

`Chrome` - <kbd>F12</kbd> → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (device mode): достаточно долго тестирую именно так, но насколько данный метод гарантирует точность, можно ли на него положится? Ведь не просто так существуют такие платные сайты как [browserstack.com](http://browserstack.com)

**P.S.** Какими методами вы пользуетесь в вашей практике фриланса?

Comment: Я в вебе не разбираюсь, но разве не нужно аналогичное делать в других браузерах?

Comment: Chrome device mode гарантирует точность размеров, но вы можете напороться на какое нибудь не поддерживаемое на устройствах css свойство, или на странную реализацию оного (например на моем android `background: gradient` выглядит как вырвиглазные полоски).

Comment: Кроме того, если вы не используете css reset, вас ждут открытия в области влияния дефолтных css на верстку, порой они поражают воображение своим разнообразием

Comment: К вышесказанному, много проблем возникало, на удивление, с *safari*. В котором в хроме в мобильном отображение показывает все отлично, а на живом айфоне верстка местами менялась в произвольных местах, также как и на windowsphone. Точность размеров да, можно подогнать, но полагаться только на *device-mode* нельзя. Ищите друзей у которых можно взять девайс и потестировать :)

Comment: Да уж, у меня вообще субъективное ощущение, что Safari нынче даже IE опережает в попрании стандартов и отсутствии поддержки фич.